# How can I analyze large dataset to help non profit with employee salary?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics

A non profit I am associated with asked me for help with setting employee salaries. I found a form 990 database which had data on things like revenue, number of employees, key employee salary and other employee salary. I have just done simple descriptive analyses and found mean, median, STD, their percentile in revenue compared to what the salary/employee # would be if the percentile was the same ETC. I also took the average/median salary and divided that by the average/median number of employees. I also did a few analyses filtering out high cost of living areas and setting the revenue to closer to theirs. I think there is some useful information for them here, but I was wondering what else I should/could be doing; I am not an expert, not used to working with this much data or with data that is not normally distributed. I am really worried about the large amount of variance making some of these descriptive statistics misleading.

Thanks in advance.
PM

Comment: If salary data are nearly normal, you can give approximate 95% confidence intervals for population means. If not nor normal you could give 95% nonparametric bootstrap CIs for several key population parameters or interest.

Answer (score 0):

You give no examples of actual salaries, but I can use R
to simulate a fictitious sample of $n=1000$ salaries with a right-skewed distribution and show how to get one style of 95% nonparametric
bootstrap CI for the population mean. (The population mean $\mu=39$ would be unknown in a real application.)

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rgamma(1000, 4, 1/6) + 15
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.82   30.08   36.70   38.64   45.51   93.82 
[1] 11.63736   # sample SD

boxplot(x)
```

[image]

```
# bootstrap
a.obs = mean(x)
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x,1000,rep=T))-a.obs)
UL = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
CI = a.obs - UL;  CI
   97.5%     2.5% 
37.90459 39.37333
```

The 95% nonparametric bootstrap Ci is $(37.90,\,39.37).$
With such a large sample size and a sample that is not
extremely different from normal, a 95% t CI is not much different: $(37.91,\, 39.36),$

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 37.91311 39.35741
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Note: Confidence intervals could also be found for the sample
mean, quartiles, and various measures of dispersion